# How can a speaker have a higher output power than input

Tags: power, speakers, output

Looking around the internet, there haven't been many answers to this questtion. Here is one which doesn't fully explain it:
[Power input smaller than output? How can this be?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26509/power-input-smaller-than-output-how-can-this-be)

So I am confused. I know that a transformer (step-up or step-down) can change the voltage and amperage, but without changing the overall **power** output. So *how* is it that a speaker (eg [Panasonic SC-CMAX5](http://www.panasonic.com/nz/consumer/tvs-home-theatre-and-audio/audio/mini-systems/sc-cmax5gs.specs.html)) have a much higher output than input? How can the energy which is put in be less than watt is put out (get it?). The SC-CMAX 5 has a nominal input ("power consumption") of 92W but an output (RMS) of 1000W.

Is it something to do with the RMS or PMPO listed on the spec sheet?

Comment: What they are calling "Normal Use" wouldn't be anywhere near 1000W of sound output, it's probably what it uses playing music with a few watts of power output.

Comment: It's not just a speaker. It's also got a "digital amplifier", and a mains power connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 92W is an "average" figure while the 1kW is a "maximum". To get a true idea of the maximum input power it could draw, we'd need to look at the information plate on the mains input. There will be capacitors in the power supply for delivering power into peaks. If you actually got it set up and outputting at peak volume it would probably draw >1kW from the mains.

It's not unusual for speaker power outputs to be really misleading, although this is the Panasonic official website and they quote RMS and PMPO. 1kW is quite loud!

Comment: Thank you. That made it somewhat clearer. So if you could graph the input power and output power without any loss, they would be exactly the same at any one instant in time...

Comment: @Adrian As long as both power domains are expressed the same way, there will be a very good degree of linearity to it, yes. PMPO versus input RMS would yield a very different kind of graph. Bear in mind though power in watts RMS is still higher than average power consumption by a mathermatical rule, at 1kW RMS output this unit can still only draw an average power of 900W: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_power#Continuous_power_and_.22RMS_power.22

Comment: Yes, although there will be some power loss as heat in the amplifier - not too much in a modern class D, but old tube amps and class A/AB configurations wasted quite a bit. So input power will be higher than output power. Provided you're measuring on the same scale, as @Asmyldof points out.

Comment: @Asmyldof: There's no such thing as "watts RMS"

Comment: @EMFields if there is no such thing, why is it quoted everywhere?

Comment: @pic50: Because people make mistakes.

Comment: @EMFields That was sort of the point of my comment. Watts RMS are quoted everywhere on audio equipment, because it's 22% above average power, but sounds more legit after the world started fighting the whole PMPO without telling you thing.

Comment: @Asmyldof: Perhaps I misunderstood what you were getting at, but my point was that, no matter how thin you slice it, RMS watts is a fiction. Do you disagree?

Comment: @EMFields No I don't, see the link I linked. I am merely saying, as you can see in every brochure, that everyone, everywhere will use the term "watt RMS" for power. Because they don't care about being right, just about sounding right to consumers. We can ignore that, or we can try to inform people about it. I chose (or attempted) the latter.

Comment: Worst case is that watts RMS and watts Peak are old fashioned marketing terms, because the real power used or output as sound is dynamic, and always changing. Its like trying to chase the shadow of a ghost.